# Updating an AWS Lambda function using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template with a Lambda resource.

In the deploy step, I need to update this Lambda function with my zip file (that I have uploaded via `aws cloudformation package`). Now, I can pass the name of the Lambda function as a parameter to SAM functionName, but when I do it, it complains that the functionName already exists.

That is fine but how do I specify to just update the code and not try to replace the Lambda function?

Comment: Just update your existing CF stack with the generated CF template (from `aws cloudformation package`). There shouldnt be an error... Otherwise please share your CF template.

Answer (score 2):

In order to update your Lambda function's code, you just have to follow this process:

```
# update code artefact and maybe compile it to target folder
# e.g. for Java using Maven: mvn clean compile package

$ aws cloudformation package ...
$ aws cloudformation deploy ...
```

This will update all resources within your template. See also [this how-to guide](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/HOWTO.md).

If you only want to update the code of a single Lambda function, you can also use [aws lambda update-function-code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html). However, this can be a bit tedious to do for different Lambda functions in a stack as you need the ARN of each function. Hence, last year I've written a small NPM tool for that called [lambda-updater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-updater) which searches for Lambda functions in a CloudFormation stack and only updates a function's code. It might be of interest for you.